# Tortoise SVN on Amazon S3

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, amazon-s3

I would like to setup a Tortoise SVN repository on my Amazon S3 server. I know how to do the setup on my local machine, and I know how to do it on a server (virtual or nonvirtual) running windows. I am not sure how to do this on amazon s3.

If you can supply steps and or references that would be much appreciated.

It doesn't necessarily need to be tortoise if there is a different route that is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to mount Amazon S3 Bucket as a virtual drive or a filesystem and configure your svn server to keep repository there.

On Windows, you may take a look at [TntDrive](http://tntdrive.com), it allows you to mount Amazon S3 Bucket as a Windows Drive or a Removable Drive. If you are under Linux, you may try to use [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/). It  allows you to mount a bucket as a local file system read/write.